# Iterating over two lists

Tags: python, list, iteration

```
def_ids = ['165153','165239']
Maxbs = ['3900','1800'] 
for def_id,Maxb in zip (def_ids, Maxbs):
        cards = func.search(definitionId=def_id, maxb=Maxb)
for card in cards:
        print ('{0} for {1}'.format(card.assetId, card.buyNowPrice))
```

I am having difficulty in trying to iterate the two lists above in parallel. I need the function to iterate through both lists and then assign all elements on both lists as one as
definitionId=def_id and the other as maxb=Maxb in parallel i.e def_ids[0] with Maxb [0].
The problem with code above is that it only does this for the last element on both lists and disregards all other elements. I need to it go over every element in order so the first def_id is 165153 and the first Maxb is 3900; the second 165239 and 1800 etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you change `cards` every time before you print. Try shifting the last two lines over, like:

```
def_ids = ['165153','165239']
Maxbs = ['3900','1800'] 
for def_id,Maxb in zip (def_ids, Maxbs):
    cards = func.search(definitionId=def_id, maxb=Maxb)
    for card in cards:
        print ('{0} for {1}'.format(card.assetId, card.buyNowPrice))
```